# Lazy Loaded Module not loaded in IE11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

My angular 7 application has two modules txxxxx module and configuration module. Both the modules are lazy loaded from the App Routing Module. The problem is that when i try to navigate to configuration module, it is throwing an error saying "Loading chunk components-configuration-configuration-module failed.". This error occurs only in Internet Explorer, its working fine in Edge,Chrome,Safari and Firefox.

These are the things i have already tried :

1. I added these files in polyfills and it doesn't 
   solve my error.

```js
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

2. I added the following line to index.ts and i doesn't solve my error:

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

My App Routing Module is this :

```js
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'trends'
  },
  {
    path: 'txxxxx',
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    loadChildren: './components/txxxxxx/txxxxx-ixxxxxx.module#Txxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  },
  {
    path: 'configuration',
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    loadChildren: './components/configuration/configuration.module#ConfigurationModule'
  }
];
```

The error that is thrown on IE is :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might help:
my problem only when i open certain routes, the problem rises and I've figured out that the the routes i am using CKEditor in is responsible for that exception when i replace it with text area the exception gone and life is happy  i was using the CK editor in

check [github ticket](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/330)